# javascript: variable undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I use a variable in javascript, it gives an error

> ReferenceError: getalletje is not defined

, depending on where I declare it.

This is where I declare the variable:

```
get_name: function(){
        var getalletje = 5;
        return getalletje;
    },
```

Where I'm trying to use the variable:

```
        self.$('.geldinuit-button').click(function(){

                self.screen_selector.show_popup('geldinuit',{
                    message: _t('Popup titel'),
                    comment: _t('getalletje'),
                    confirm: function(){
                        window.alert(getalletje);
                    },
                });

        });
```

It gives an error like this.

But: If I put `var getalletje = 5;`just above `self.$('.geldinuit-button').click(function(){`, it works.

Something extra I need to do?

Edit for Shomz: This is the full code:

```
.............                
self.set_smart_status(status.newValue);
            });

            this.$el.click(function(){
                self.pos.connect_to_proxy();
            });
        },
    });

    module.PosWidget = module.PosBaseWidget.extend({
        template: 'PosWidget',
        init: function() { 
            this._super(arguments[0],{});
            this.pos = new module.PosModel(this.session,{pos_widget:this});
            this.pos_widget = this; //So that pos_widget's childs have pos_widget set automatically

.............................
............................

    get_name: function(){
        var getalletje = 5;
        return getalletje;
    },
...........................
...........................
                self.$('.geldinuit-button').click(function(){

                        self.screen_selector.show_popup('geldinuit',{
                            message: _t('Popup titel'),
                            comment: _t('getalletje'),
                            confirm: function(){
                                window.alert( this.get_name() );
                            },
                        });

                });
..........................
```

Comment: You're encountering the effects of basic scoping rules.

Comment: This is a matter of scope :) Maybe look it up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: A variable declared inside a function is not available outside that function; that's the whole point of being able to declare *local* non-global variables.

Comment: Yes there is something extra you need to do, but you already said what it was: "If I put var getalletje = 5;just above self.$('.geldinuit-button').click(function(){, it works."

Comment: You have to do a global variable, put the variable at the beginning

Comment: @bicho so what's the purpose of that getter function if you suggest the global variable?

Comment: The purposse of the function is to set a value to global variable, then you could use this variable in any function @Shomz

Comment: @bicho Umm, no... getter functions **GET** values, they don't **SET** values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scoping issue - the variable you declare is available only locally. To get its value, you can do something like:

```
confirm: function(){
    window.alert( yourObject.get_name() );
},
```

where `yourObject` is the object that you defined the `get_name` method for.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. But I found my answer below. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It has to work, just make sure you replace `yourObject` with the real object you're using (is it `self`?). You're welcome.

Comment: Just to make sure: This is my code:
module.PosWidget = module.PosBaseWidget.extend({
        template: 'PosWidget',
        init: function() { 
            this._super(arguments[0],{});
            this.pos = new module.PosModel(this.session,{pos_widget:this});
            this.pos_widget = this; //So that pos_widget's childs have pos_widget set automatically
.........................

Is "PosWidget" the object?

Comment: It's hard to see here in the comments... what do you have above `get_name: function(){`? Inside what function it is?

Comment: I've put the "complete" code in my OP. I also tried to use this.get_name(). But also didn't work.

Comment: Should be self. Works with self!

Comment: Still not quite clear, but I think it should be `module.PosWidget`. Oh, so it was `self`, nice. (see my first comment here) :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't access variable outside of the function you declare it in. If you want to access variable in a global way you should declare it outside of get_name.
In your case I don't see the point but the following should work:

```
var getalletje = 0;

get_name: function(){
        getalletje = 5;
        return getalletje;
    },

self.$('.geldinuit-button').click(function(){

                self.screen_selector.show_popup('geldinuit',{
                    message: _t('Popup titel'),
                    comment: _t('getalletje'),
                    confirm: function(){
                        window.alert(getalletje);
                    },
                });

    });
```

also, shouldn't:

```
comment: _t('getalletje'),
```

become

```
comment: _t(getalletje),
```

**UPDATE**

Also, in your case this declaration isn't useful. I don't know if you changed your code when asking your question but in this case doing only:

```
self.$('.geldinuit-button').click(function(){
                var getalletje = 5;

            self.screen_selector.show_popup('geldinuit',{
                message: _t('Popup titel'),
                comment: _t('getalletje'),
                confirm: function(){
                    window.alert(getalletje);
                },
            });

});
```

Comment: This is a bad approach, not only because it pollutes the globalspace, but it beats the purpose of that getter function.

Comment: code sheets get read from top to bottom: so first the declarations, then the code line and functions using your variables.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong... Didn't work. I just read the value of the variable defined on the top instead of the value the function should give it...

Comment: yes, cause there is a typo in the way you call you variables. (Or I have a typo). I've updated my answer with some considerations from Shomz